# How to print every rows with Pandas using Python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

How can I print "The date is not available" and missing rows with Pandas, as I normally do from the webpage? This is my code that gives me two different outputs:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./drivers/chromedriver")
browser.get('https://www.ebay.it/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=3060&_sacat=0&_sop=15')
import time
time.sleep(2)
cookie = browser.find_element_by_id("gdpr-banner-accept").click()
page_source = browser.page_source
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
results = (soup.find("ul", {"class": "srp-results"}))
results.findAll("li")
items = results.findAll("li")
rows = []
for item in items:
    titleElement = item.find("h3")
    priceElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})
    dateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__time-end"})
    if titleElement:
        newListingTag = titleElement.find("span", {"class": "LIGHT_HIGHLIGHT"})
        if newListingTag:
            newListingTag.extract()
        print(titleElement.text)

    if priceElement:
        print(priceElement.text)

    if dateElement:
        print(dateElement.text)
    else:
        print("The date is not available")


results.findAll("li")
items = results.findAll("li")
rows = []
for item in items:
    titleElement = item.find("h3")
    priceElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})
    dateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__time-end"})
    if titleElement and priceElement and dateElement:
        newListingTag = titleElement.find("span", {"class": "LIGHT_HIGHLIGHT"})
        if newListingTag:
            newListingTag.extract()
        row = [dateElement.text, titleElement.text, priceElement.text]
        rows.append(row)
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None, "display.max_colwidth", None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=["Purchase Date", "Title", "Price"])
print(df)
```

Here's the first output:

```
NUOVO MSI GeForce RTX 3060 12GB GPU
EUR 488,25
(Martedì, 13:02)

GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 3060 Ti OC 8GB Eagle
EUR 499,88
(Domenica, 14:47)

MSI GTX 1650 VENTUS XS 4G OC Graphics card GF GTX 1650 4 GB GDDR5 V809-3060R
EUR 532,50
The date is not available
...
```

ecc. ecc. (it includes about 50 elements)

---

On the other hand, this is the second output (it lacks about 34 elements compared to the first output, why?)

```
0   (Martedì, 13:02)   NUOVO MSI GeForce RTX 3060 12GB GPU                                                           
EUR 488,25

1   (Domenica, 14:47)  GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 3060 Ti OC 8GB Eagle                                                     
EUR 499,88

2   (Giovedì, 22:11)   Inno 3d GeForce RTX 3060 TWIN x2 OC 12gb GDDR 6 GPU neu&ovp - spedizione veloce ✅             EUR 510,00
...
```

ecc. ecc.

Furthermore, I noticed the second output only shows rows with exact dates.

Thanks for answers and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with Selenium, but after checking out that site, it looks like not all listings will have the class `s-item__time-end`. An alternative tag to include might be: `s-item__purchase-options-with-icon`, which allows for Buy It Now and other variations.  Just add another variable, like the following:

`dateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__time-end"})`
`altDateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__purchase-options-with-icon"})`

With the original setup, the validation check might fail if `dateElement` is None, as in the following line:

`if titleElement and priceElement and dateElement`

You could also try an empty-string buffer with the `dateElement` to see if that allows for blank results.

`dateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__time-end"}) or ""`

Comment: I add an if statement like this to get every product's names:                     if item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__time-end"}):
        dateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__time-end"})
    else:
        dateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost"})                     Now, i would like to write "Not available" instead of item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost"})